# VBA Access Data Type

Tags: ms-access, type-conversion, vba

Is it possible by using

```
DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, acSpreadsheetTypeText, strFile, strPathFile, blnHasFieldNames
```

To change the data type of one of the columns to text from a number? using VBA Access?

Comment: Can you please give some explanation about the issue?

Comment: I believe you are trying to import a text file into Access, and then after the import you want to change a column that was imported and interpreted as a number, to now be a data type of TEXT? If so, you could either create an import specification that set's the data type of that column, or you could alter the table after the import, like: currentdb.Execute "ALTER TABLE [MyTable] ALTER COLUMN [FldA] TEXT(100)"

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub AlterTableX1()

    Dim dbs As Database

    ' Modify this line to include the path to Northwind
    ' on your computer.
    Set dbs = OpenDatabase("Northwind.mdb")

    ' Add the Salary field to the Employees table 
    ' and make it a Money data type.
    dbs.Execute "ALTER TABLE Employees " _
        & "ADD COLUMN SomeNumber Number;"

    dbs.Close

End Sub
```

See this for more info.

[MS Access SQL, changing data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10433060/ms-access-sql-changing-data-type)